# Fitting a density (distribution) to a histogram in Matlab

Tags: matlab, distribution

I have a matrix M(mx2). The first column is my bins and the second one is the frequency associated with each bin. I want to fit a smooth curve to this histogram in matlab, but most of what I have tried (like kdensity) needs the real distribution of data, which I don't have them.

Is there any functions that can take the bins and their frequency and give me a smooth curve of bin-freq. ?

Comment: why isn't it a simple curve fitting with `x=m(:,1)` and `y=m(:,2)`?

Comment: I just have a few data and smoothing does not work here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a hack that should work for you: generate a sample from your histogram, then run ksdensity on the sample.

```
rng(42) % seed RNG to make reproducible

% make example histogram
N = 1e3;
bins = -5:5;
counts = round(rand(size(bins))*N);
M = [bins' counts'];

figure
hold on
bar(M(:,1), M(:,2));


% draw a sample from it
sampleCell = arrayfun( @(i) repmat(M(i,1), M(i,2), 1), 1:size(M,1), 'uniformoutput', false )';
sample = cat(1, sampleCell{:});
[f, x] = ksdensity(sample);
plot(x, f*sum(M(:,2)));
```

Comment: It produces a strange curve for this data: M(:,1) = [1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18]; M(:,2) = [0
69
138
207
276
345
483
1035
1173
1380
2414
2759
7932
10000
5173
1725
1035
0];

Comment: @Sam You may need to adjust the bandwidth of the KDE for certain samples. For your example, try `[f, x] = ksdensity(sample, 'bandwidth', 1);`